# Is there a way to read all the rows until an empty row is encountered using Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I have numerous rows in excel and the rows are filled with garbage values after an empty row.
Is there a way to read only the records before the first empty row in excel using Python pandas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not aware of if read_excel can do this. If you import an empty line from excel, the column values for those rows will be filled with NaN, then you could select the values till a first row is filled with all NaN's.

I am assuming your data is something like this, where you have an empty row and data following it is garbage (I included multiple empty rows and garbage following it)
[image]

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'Book1.xlsx') # read the file

print df 
'''
   col1 col2 col3
0     1    2    3
1     1    2    3
2     1    2    3
3     1    2    3
....
10    1    2    3
11  NaN  NaN  NaN
12    x    x    x
....
18  NaN  NaN  NaN
19  NaN  NaN  NaN
20    y    y    y
21    y    y    y
....
'''

first_row_with_all_NaN = df[df.isnull().all(axis=1) == True].index.tolist()[0]
# gives me the first row number of the row that has all the values to be NaN. 
'''
11
'''

print df.loc[0:first_row_with_all_NaN-1]

# then I use loc to select the rows from 0 to  first row with all NaN's-1

'''
 col1 col2 col3
0     1    2    3
1     1    2    3
2     1    2    3
3     1    2    3
4     1    2    3
5     1    2    3
6     1    2    3
7     1    2    3
8     1    2    3
9     1    2    3
10    1    2    3
'''
```