# Pythons version of VBA's xldown using Pandas pd.read_excel function

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

When using VBA, if you want to find the last row in a table of data you'd use the `xldown` command.  This is an example of starting cell `A1` and dropping down until the last row of data is found (defined as the row before a row of blank values":

```
Sub GoToLast()
'move to the last cell occupied in the current region of cells
   Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
End Sub
```

When using the `pd.read_excel` function, how can you code a similar feature? For example, if someone were to start at row 11 of column A, how would they use a dynamic variable in the `nrows` field below to grab the exact range of data that they need rather than the hard coded value of 10 rows?

```
tempTable = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(r, file), 
                                       sheet_name='data sheet', 
                                       header=10, 
                                       nrows=10)
```

Comment: `nrows` is optional argument, don't supply it if you want all rows

Comment: And as a side advice- in VBA avoid to use `.Select`. It is almost never needed (i.e. you need to select only in very limited specific cases)

Comment: @buran what if there is data from rows 11 to 20, but then a blank row in row 21, but then more data below that blank row, and I only want the values from rows 11 to 20? Will it return the correct values in this case if I don't include the ```nrows``` value?

Comment: no, it will read all data and will put `NaN` for the blank rows

Comment: check e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44030415/4046632 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/47039309/4046632 Google `pandas read excel till first blank row` and check the SO answers